# Fake IP on Codeception functional tests

Tags: yii2, codeception

I´m using Yii2 and Codeception to run tests.

When i run a **functional** test, the `$SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` is not defined. How can i mockup the ip to use in those tests.

I have tried `$SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = '127.0.0.1'`, but it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Yesterday I faced with such problem, and I have found the solution! So, my solution related to Yii2 framework, but I think that you will be able to modify it for your environment.

1. Extend your codeception module (Yii2 for me):

```php
<?php

namespace codeception;

use Codeception\Module\Yii2;

class CustomModule extends Yii2
{
    protected function recreateClient()
    {
        parent::recreateClient();

        if ($ip = ($this->config['ip'] ?? null)) {
            $this->client->setServerParameter('REMOTE_ADDR', $ip);
        }
    }
}
```

2. Go to codeception.yaml config and set your `ip`:

```yaml
actor: MyTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - \Helper\E2eCommon
        - Asserts
        - Mockery
        # here
        - \codeception\CustomModule:
            configFile: 'codeception/_config/config.php'
        - REST:
            # here
            depends: \codeception\CustomModule
            part: Json
    config:
        # and here!
        \codeception\CustomModule:
            ip: 192.168.1.1 # ip mock here!

extensions:
    enabled:
        - \ResetYiiContainerExtension
```

that's all! enjoy :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Find 2 files (if project built on [yii2-app-basic](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-basic) template - remove from path dir `common/`):

   - `common/config/codeception-local.php`
   - `environments/dev/common/config/codeception-local.php`
2. Add inside of array:

```php
[
    ...
    'on beforeAction' => static function () {
        $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = '127.0.0.1';
    },
    ...
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your functional Helper class under tests/_support (if it doesn't exist):

```
class FunctionalHelper extends \Codeception\Module {
    public function _before(\Codeception\TestInterface $test)
    {
        $this->getModule('Yii2')->client->defaultServerVars = array_merge(
            $this->getModule('Yii2')->client->defaultServerVars,
            ['REMOTE_ADDR' => '127.0.0.1']
        );            
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have an example of how to use this?

Comment: I have edited my answer so the usage is more clear now hopefully. Read about helpers in codeception documentation https://codeception.com/docs-2.0/03-ModulesAndHelpers#Helpers

Comment: I saw the documentation on the helpers, I was hoping more for some example code on how you implemented with the functional testing. Are you using Yii1 or Yii2? Any chance you could post your pieces?

Comment: I'm not sure what pieces you mean. All the code is in the answer; you need nothing more. And I am using Yii2, Yii1 is different matter.

Answer (score 0):

For versions of codecept >=2.4 and <4.0 try to use something similar to:

```php
class Helper extends \Codeception\Module
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function _before(\Codeception\TestInterface $test)
    {
        $this->getModule('Yii2')->client->setServerParameter('REMOTE_ADDR', '127.0.0.1');
    }
}
```

and don't forget to enable it in a `*.suite.yml` file:

```
modules:
    enabled:
        - \tests\Helper\Helper
```